# Microsoft Dynamics AX SQL JOIN Translation

Tags: sql-server, join, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I was wondering how Axapta translates its SQL Statements and came across this: 
[how-joins-in-x-select-statement-are-translated-into-t-sql](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/dynamicsaxhints/archive/2015/05/23/how-joins-in-x-select-statement-are-translated-into-t-sql)

This is the first example given on the site.

JOIN in X++:

```
select AccountNum from custTable
    join TaxGroupId from custGroup
    where custGroup.CustGroup == custTable.CustGroup;
```

CROSS JOIN in T-SQL:

```
SELECT T1.ACCOUNTNUM, T1.RECID, T2.TAXGROUPID, T2.RECID
FROM CUSTTABLE T1 CROSS JOIN CUSTGROUP T2
WHERE ((T1.PARTITION=?) AND (T1.DATAAREAID=?))
  AND (((T2.PARTITION=?) AND (T2.DATAAREAID=?)) 
   AND (T2.CUSTGROUP=T1.CUSTGROUP))
```

I was now wondering what the question mark means in this statement.
The `?` is marked as error because of wrong syntax.

What does `WHERE ((T1.PARTITION=?) AND (T1.DATAAREAID=?))` mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These fields are part of Data Isolation implementation in Dynamics AX. More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj677285.aspx)

Field `T1.PARTITION` relates to Partitions:

> Partitions divide and isolate the business data of an installation by using special processing that the AOS applies to data queries. This special processing occurs immediately before the queries are sent to the underlying Microsoft SQL Server database when a system field named Partition is present in a queried table.

Field `T1.DATAAREAID` relates to company or legal entity:

> Each partition contains at least one company or legal entity. A legal entity occurs in only one partition. When you create a legal entity, the system assigns it to the current partition. The legal entity can never be moved to another partition. However, its data can be exported from the partition and then imported to another company in another partition.

The question mark would be eventually substituted by the actual values of Partitions and Companies, depending of the context the statement was called from.

Comment: what about fields like TAXGROUPID or something like that. It isn't a system field but in the last example on the page it is also used with =? . Is that because it is in a subquery and is substitued there too?

Comment: This is also a placeholder that will be substituted with "Std" in that example. This way, the SQL server recieves the parameterized query (which is shown in the blog) and values for parameters, which will vary depanding on the context.

Answer (score 1):

The question marks are placeholders to enable the SQL server to compute execution plans for queries where the search values change often.

> Microsoft Dynamics AX may pass either parameters (placeholders) or
>   literals (actual values) in queries.
>
> • Parameters allow Microsoft Dynamics AX and the database server to
>   reuse the query when search values change. They are preferred for
>   high-frequency queries.
>
> • Literals allow the database server to optimize the query for a
>   specific piece of information. This provides an optimal query for that
>   piece of information, but the database server must perform the
>   optimization for every query executed. Literals may be used for long
>   running queries such as complex joins.
>
> A developer can override the default use of literals by specifying
>   parameters in their code, or an administrator can override the use of
>   literals in the Server Configuration Utility.

- [Tune database settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa569634(v=ax.10).aspx) for AX 4.0, but still relevant for AX 2012.